# Understanding Rails eager_load_paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want Rails to automatically load all the class files I have under lib. I can achieve this by adding the following into **application.rb**:

```
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.eager_load_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Here's the thing- this works in development as well, even though `config.eager_load = false` in development. Can someone explain that?